# Does memory get allocated with Fortran read() with no I/O list?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, intel-vtune

I am reading an ascii file with Intel Fortran opened as:

```
open(10, file=trim(file_name), status='old', action='read', iostat=ierr, iomsg=msg)
```

To skip some file lines which I do not want to store I am using read() with no I/O list:

```
read(10, *)
```

VTune reports 53 GB allocated at the read() with no I/O list:

[image]

Is that memory really allocated or is it that VTune incorrectly identifies memory allocation? What causes this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have 53 GB physical/virtual memory? How large is the file? Is the file mmaped?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: "Maybe". I realise this is not a useful answer, but it is totally up to the implementation as to how internally it performs the iteration, and could easily change between implementation, even from the same vendor.

Comment: @francescalus I have 500 GB of physical memory. The file size is 65 MB, it has 1.5 million lines, and it is being read in parallel by 40 procs using MPI. Each rank reads and stores its own fraction of lines, and skips the other lines using read() with no arguments. The file is not mmaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not 53+GB of virtual memory being allocated at that point. The read with no I/O list likely allocates no memory at all.(I am a former Intel Fortran compiler developer.)